# Finding A Quadratic Whose Roots Equals Intercept On Axes and Area Equals A

Tags: analytic-geometry, quadratics

How to find the quadratic equation whose roots are the x and y intercepts of the line passing through $(1,1)$ and making a triangle of area A with the axes?

Ok I'm getting $(1-m)(1-1/m)=A$ and $(x-(1-m))(x-(1-1/m))=y$.But how to proceed from here?How to get the sum of roots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the quadratic equation is $ax^2+bx+c=0$.  Without loss of generality, we assume that $a=1$.  Then, the roots are

$$x_{\pm}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2}$$

The product of the roots are simply

$$x_+x_-=c$$

and since we must have $\frac12 x_+x_-=A$, then $c=2A$.  Our quadratic equation is now of the form $x^2+bx+2A=0$.

We also know that the line that passes through $(0,x_+)$ and $(x_-,0)$ also passes through $(1,1)$.  Thus, we have

$$\frac{x_+-1}{1}=\frac{x_+}{x_-}\implies x_+x_-=x_++x_-\implies c=-b\implies b=-c=-2A$$

Thus, the quadratic equation is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x^2-2Ax+2A=0}$$

Answer (score 0):

Call the gradient $m$, the x-intercept $a$ and the y-intercept $b$.

Then we have:

$y = mx + b$

$x = \frac{y}{m} + a$

Plugging in our known point (1, 1) and rearranging:

$1 - b = m$

$1 - a =\frac{1}{m}$

As we're not interested in the value of $m$, eliminate it by multiplying the  two equations together:

$(1 - b)(1 - a) = 1$

Which simplifies to:

$ab - (a+b) = 0$

$ab = a+b$

Meanwhile the area of the triangle is $\frac{1}{2} ab = A$ so $ab = 2A$

Product of roots is 2A

And plugging this back into the earlier equation,

$ab = a+b = 2A $

Sum of roots is also 2A.

So this gives us the final equation $x^2 - 2Ax + 2A = 0$.

Comment: @Dr. MV any idea?

Comment: @Dr.MV you're  right of course. Sorry. Will delete or rewrite.

Comment: @IanF1 No worry.  Math is supposed to be fun, I believe.  And Sanchayan always posts the coolest questions.  Where does he come up with these?

Comment: Rewrote my answer completely. Note for confused future readers: All comments above are about my first attempt which was just wrong :)

Comment: @Dr.MV sometimes it feels good to be complimented ^_^!!Well most of them are from my books or net :-)!!